# Why is Puppet creating these files after every run?

Tags: puppet

I've recently noticed that the Puppet agent is creating zero-length files with the name of "1" in directories I've defined as:

```
file { '/opt/foo/':                                                                                                  
   ensure  => directory,                                                                                               
    owner   => 'bar',                                                                                                
    group   => 'bar',                                                                                                
}
```

Results in:

```
ls -lah /opt/foo
drwxr-xr-x  2 bar bar 4.0K Feb 23 18:58 .
drwxr-xr-x. 7 root   root   4.0K Feb 23 18:42 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      0 Feb 23 18:59 1
```

Puppet version: 3.7.4

CentOS 6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions and the timestamp on the directory and file don't match; that puppet resource isn't creating that file.

Some other puppet resource, or something else on your system, is doing that.

Comment: Ah, good catch!